# Zend Form - I can't load element's decorator class file

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, decorator, autoloader

I've got some form like this:

```
class Form_RegistrationForm extends Zend_Form {

    public function init()
    {

           [...]
           $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
           $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
           [...]

           $elements = array($username, $email, [...]);
           foreach($elements as $element) {

               $element->addPrefixPath('Form_Decorator', 'Form/Decorator', 'decorator');
               $element->addValidator('CustomErrors');

               $this->AddElement($element);

           }
    }
}
```

I've my decorator in `/application/modules/Form/Decorator/CustomErrors.php`.
I've named decorator by: `class Form_Decorator_CustomErrors extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract`

The problem is that Zend can't find my decorator.
I'm getting error: Message: Plugin by name 'CustomErrors' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_Validate_: Zend/Validate/

It's a litte werid because it looks like Zend ignores my defined path.

My appication.ini file:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.view[] =
url.full = http://87.199.35.20/Kreskoweczki/bp/
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = 
resources.db.params.dbname = kreskoweczki
resources.db.params.charset = utf8
resources.db.params.prefix = kres_

;Mail transport settings

;mail.smpt - when false - sendmail is used

mail.smtp=true
mail.host=127.0.0.1
mail.smtpconfig.name=localhost
mail.smtpconfig.port=25
;mail.smtpconfig.auth = plain | login | crammd5
mail.smtpconfig.auth=
mail.smtpconfig.username=
mail.smtpconfig.password=
mail.from=no-reply@example.com

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

My index.php:

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
 set_include_path(
    '../library/' . PATH_SEPARATOR .    
    '../application/modules/' . PATH_SEPARATOR .    
    '../application/' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
    get_include_path() 
);

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

Comment: What `$element->getPluginLoader('decorator')->getPaths()` returns? Call it after `$element->addPrefixPath('Form_Decorator', 'Form/Decorator', 'decorator');`

Answer (score 0):

// for all elements:

```
$form->addElementPrefixPath('My_Decorator', 'My/Decorator/', 'decorator');
```

// Overwrite existing decorators with this single one:

```
$element->setDecorators(array('CustomDecorator'));
```